# Xamarin.Forms App Hosting - Switching images from server

Tags: c#, forms, image, xamarin, hosting

I've builted some apps as demos but I have never uploaded one to the stores.

I'm having doubts about the hositng options (between AWS and Azure). I've been asked to build an app that has promotional images, and the client would like to change the images every month.

I wanted to know whats the best way to build my Xamarin.Forms app so that it can consult this image with a fixed link or fixed name, so that when I need to swicth it with another image, I can do it at the server, and the phone will get that new picture.

I thought about uploadig images to a picture service like IMGUR, and the go to Azure easy tables and change the link (I read Easy tables will desapear Nov 11, 2019 that concerns me https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/updates/removing-easy-tables-and-easy-apis-from-azure-app-service/).

I also thought about reading a stream for each image and using a website like:
https://www.browserling.com/tools/image-to-base64
To convert my image to a stream of text and change that serverside.

I need a list of "Coupons" or images that must change each month.

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView  x:Name="CouponsListView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding CouponsList}"
                       RowHeight="180">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout   Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="180" >
                            <StackLayout   Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="180" WidthRequest="180">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Place.ImgUrl}" HeightRequest="180" WidthRequest="180"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout   Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  WidthRequest="180" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  VerticalOptions="Center"
                                TextColor="Black" /> 
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I expect to deploy the App just once to Apple Store and Play Store, and when the client ask for changes I can just go into my server and somehow switch the current list of images with new ones.

If theres something better than easy tables for this I would love to hear your opinions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Implement what @Jason shared above. Then in UI use ffimageloading to cache the image. Whenever cache expires or url get changed; cache will also get refreshed!

Comment: Hi thanks for your awnsers, I understand I can reference a Json file with all the images urls and store this file inside on of the projects folder. But when I compile this into an .ipa or .apk I woudl have to republish the app in the stores to change that json file. Am i wrong?

Comment: Anybody can explain how to achive editing a Json file thats packeged within the app without republishing?

Comment: You said you gonna have server. Return those image urls using your server than embedding your json in your app

Comment: Hi, I mean, I asking for advice in how to manage this. I just want the database to store app data, Im not sure if AWS or Azure App Service can be configured to return thos urls from the json file.

Comment: You can do that on both. Its all your choice. If you have existing resources in azure then just create azure web app and deploy one simple api that returns list of urls. Whenever you need to update just update web service and deploy. Dont need to redeploy app